# Runtime width of UILabel in UITableCellView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

I have a UITableView with some cells (in subtitle style) which can contain an unlimited amount of text in both the title and subtitle fields (this is a client requirement and they can't be persuaded otherwise). I've built some methods which I call in the heightForRow:atIndexPath to determine the height of the UILabels. These methods are dependent on knowing the width of the UILabels in question. I have no idea how to get this value. At present I've thrown in a value which I extracted using a log statement on the Simulator running in iPhone 5S mode. This is not a stable solution. Any ideas how to achieve this?

Here are the methods I'm using at present:

```
-(CGFloat) heightForSubtitleCellWithTitleString:(NSString *)titleString withFont:(UIFont *)titleFont withDetailString:(NSString *)detailString withFont:(UIFont *)detailFont withTableView:(UITableView *)tableView

{
    if (!detailString) {
        detailString = @"Dummy text!"; // <-- Hacky, but when there is no detail text, we need to make room for the placeholder text.
    }
    CGRect rectForDetailString = [self rectForString:detailString withFont:detailFont withWidth:tableView.bounds.size.width - 54]; // 54 is the difference between the width of the label and tableview at runtime. On an iPhone 5 screen. Mæh.
    CGRect rectForTitleString = [self rectForString:titleString withFont:titleFont withWidth:tableView.bounds.size.width - 54];
    CGFloat height = ceilf(CGRectGetHeight(rectForTitleString) + CGRectGetHeight(rectForDetailString) + 10); // 10 is the padding between labels and top and bottom of the cell
    return height;
}

-(CGRect) rectForString:(NSString *)string withFont:(UIFont *)font withWidth:(CGFloat)width
{
    CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(width, LONG_MAX);
    NSMutableParagraphStyle * paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    NSStringDrawingOptions options = NSStringDrawingTruncatesLastVisibleLine |
    NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin;
    NSDictionary *attr = @{NSFontAttributeName : font,
                           NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraphStyle};
    CGRect labelBounds = [string boundingRectWithSize:maximumLabelSize
                                              options:options
                                           attributes:attr
                                              context:nil];
    return labelBounds;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

lets take Height = 30 of text label, For fixed height

```
label.text = detailstext;
float lableWidth = [label sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(INT_MAX, 30)].width;
```

Comment: The height of the label isn't fixed though. The point of the code I've included is to ascertain the height of the UITableViewCell, which contains 2 UILabels, one on top of the other since the cell is in 'subtitle' style.

Answer (score 0):

With autolayout you can pin your label's top, trailing and leading edges and let its content decide its own size. Set number of lines to 0. Also with auto layout the UITableViewCell calculates the cell height depending on its content view's subview's height.

The below method can be used to calculate the configured cell's height dynamically. But you need to take care as this method gets called for each and every cell.
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

So if the number of cells are more then there is a performance issue/lag. To fix this we can use a new api below added in iOS8.

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

This method allows a table view to calculate the actual height of each cell lazily.

Comment: You would also need to set:                                                                               
`self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;`